# Defining a range based on contiguous duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a report that our software spit out that I'm trying to create something more useful out of. The report lists everyone's permission toggles on the system, like so:

```
JANE DOE      PERMISSION 1    N
JANE DOE      PERMISSION 2    N
JANE DOE      PERMISSION 3    Y
JOHN SMITH    PERMISSION 1    Y
JOHN SMITH    PERMISSION 2    N
JOHN SMITH    PERMISSION 3    Y
```

I am turning this into a table that uses INDEX/MATCH to check whether the toggle is at Y or N, like so:

```
             JOHN   JANE
PERMISSION 1  Y      N
PERMISSION 2  N      N
PERMISSION 3  Y      Y
```

My problem is that we have over 100 permissions and 200 employees. The formula I'm using is this:

```
=INDEX(toggle,MATCH(1,INDEX((B$1=employee)*($A4=permission),0,1),0))
```

So my INDEX/MATCH is checking a list of 20,000 values to populate 20,000 different cells. Unsurprisingly it's taking a pretty long time to calculate.

The original report is already organized alphabetically, so each employee's permissions are grouped together. What I'd like to do is tell my index to only look at the range constituting the current employee's permissions. So for instance, I could have a helper row that calculates the range for John Doe, and then use INDIRECT() to point my index at only that range.

I have found a few questions involving contiguous duplicates but most involve conditional formatting. I found one solution involving a macro that would automatically create a named range for each set of contiguous values, but I don't want to clutter up my name manager (again, more than 100 employees and that's only including one user group for now) and I'd really prefer not to use VBA unless it's the only option.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table? Then you can apply a filter for "Current employee" and only get back that information... or what have you. Doing this with formulas is going to be unnecessarily expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you can do even better than your suggestion of restricting the ranges referenced within your current formula set-up.

The ONLY reason that you are suffering from such protracted calculation times with your current set-up is due to the fact that you are using an *array-processing* construction. What's more, this is easily avoidable, and requires the use of just a single additional column within your data, viz:

  1) Within that additional column, enter a formula which performs a simple concatenation of the entries in the
  *employee*
  and
  *permission*
  columns, e.g.
  `=F2&"|"&G2`
  (where, for example,
  `F2`
  might contain "Jane" and
  `G2`
  "PERMISSION 1"; also note the additional "|" as separator, which is good practice in general), and copy to all cells within that column.

  2) Name this range within Name Manager, e.g.
  *concat*
  .

The simple, non-array equivalent of the formula you posted is then:

`=INDEX(toggle,MATCH(B$1&"|"&$A4,concat,0))`

and will be far, far faster to calculate.

Regards